# Evento al hacer click fuera del JQuery ContextMenu Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Estoy implementando este plugin de jquery en mi proyecto: https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html

Como verán en el script, estoy llamando a ciertas funciones bajo la sexta linea, y justo debajo de esos if, estoy cambiando el background-color del div que desplegó el contextMenu. El problema es que esa acción se aplica solo si hice click en alguna de las opciones del contextMenu y no así cuando haga click fuera del contextMenu, lo cual necesito.

el script:

```
$(function() {         // Context menú, lo del click derecho
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '.context-menu-one',
            trigger: 'hover',
            delay: 500,
            callback: function(key, options) {
                if(key=="Editar") Editar_hora($(this).text());
                if(key=="Eliminar") Eliminar_hora($(this).text());
                if(key=="Nueva fila") Nueva_fila($(this).text());
                if(key=="Nuevo Horario") Nuevo_horario($(this).text());
                $(this).css("background-color","#5589DC");
            },
            items: {
                "Editar": {name: "Editar hora del turno", icon: "edit"},
                "Nueva fila": {name: "Nueva fila", icon: "add"},
                "Nuevo horario": {name: "Nuevo turno", icon: "add"},
                "Eliminar": {name: "Eliminar este turno", icon: "delete"},
                "sep1": "---------",
                "quit": {name: "Cerrar", icon: function(){
                    return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
                }}
            }
        });

        $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
            console.log('clicked', this);
        })    
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución en la documentación y está bastante simple:
https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#events

el código queda así:

```
$(function() {         // Context menú, lo del click derecho
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one',
        trigger: 'hover',
        delay: 500,
        autoHide: true,
        callback: function(key, options) {
            if(key=="Editar") Editar_hora($(this).text());
            if(key=="Eliminar") Eliminar_hora($(this).text());
            if(key=="Nueva fila") Nueva_fila($(this).text());
            if(key=="Nuevo Horario") Nuevo_horario($(this).text());
            $(this).css("background-color","#5589DC");
        },
        items: {
            "Editar": {name: "Editar hora del turno", icon: "edit"},
            "Nueva fila": {name: "Nueva fila", icon: "add"},
            "Nuevo horario": {name: "Nuevo turno", icon: "add"},
            "Eliminar": {name: "Eliminar este turno", icon: "delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Cerrar", icon: function(){
                return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
            }}
        },
        events: {
          hide : function(options){
            $(this).css("background-color","#5589DC");
        }}
    });

    $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('clicked', this);
    })    
});
```

Había buscado un montón y no daba en el clavo por saber poco inglés >.< pero ahí está.

**EDIT:**

El trozo de código que me faltaba era este, que no viene incluido en el plugin, sino que lo encontré en su documentación:

```
,
        events: {
          hide : function(options){
            $(this).css("background-color","#5589DC");
        }}
```

Básicamente lanza un evento cuando se esconde el ContextMenu, se aprecia que estoy cambiando el background-color, pero esta vez sí lo hará cuando se haga click fuera del ContextMenú.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar (dentro de la respuesta) en qué consiste el cambio que hiciste y por qué funciona?

Comment: he editado, dime si se entiende.

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias